# Por que não estou conseguindo colocar o conteudo

Tags: javascript

Estou com uma dúvida quando quanto a captura de elemento com o Dom;

Exemplo

```
let paragrafo = document.getElementById('paragrafo').innerHTML;
```

Certo até ai tudo bem, com isso eu consigo ver o conteúdo do meu paragrafo, mas por que eu não consigo alterar o valor do meu elemento capturado, como exemplo abaixo

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <p id="paragrafo"></p>
        <button onclick="colocarConteudo()">inserir texto</button>


    <script type="text/javascript">
        let conteudo = document.getElementById('paragrafo').innerHTML;
        function colocarConteudo(){
            conteudo = `Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
                        tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
                        quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
                        consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
                        cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
                        proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.`;
        }
    </script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: let nao é usada pra variavel local?, tente com o var

Comment: Cara tentei mas não deu também

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Você esta pegando o `innerHTML` *(conteúdo string)* de um `HTMLElement` e colocando em uma variável, ao fazer isso `conteudo = 'outro texto';` você apenas esta mudando o valor dentro da variável e não no HTML.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <p id="paragrafo">meu texto</p>
        <button onclick="colocarConteudo()">inserir texto</button>


    <script type="text/javascript">
        let conteudo = document.getElementById('paragrafo').innerHTML;
        function colocarConteudo(){
            console.log( 'Nome do constructor:', conteudo.constructor.name );
            console.log( 'Var:', conteudo )
            conteudo = 'novo texto';
            console.log( 'Var:', conteudo );
        }
    </script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Me parece que você quer pegar `HTMLElement`, ou seja, `document.getElementById('paragrafo')` e depois substituir seu conteúdo (`innerHTML`) por outro +/- assim:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <p id="paragrafo"></p>
        <button onclick="colocarConteudo()">inserir texto</button>


    <script type="text/javascript">
        let conteudo = document.getElementById('paragrafo');
        function colocarConteudo(){
            console.log( 'Nome do constructor:', conteudo.constructor.name );
            console.log( 'Var:', conteudo);
            conteudo.innerHTML = `Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
                        tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
                        quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
                        consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
                        cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
                        proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.`;
        }
    </script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Referencias: [HTMLElement](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement), [Element](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/Element), [innerHTML](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML)